# Smooks, Read CSV, get First Record as Header info and process the rest as Records

Tags: xml, csv, split, css-selectors, smooks

I am stuck on a situation where I have to read a CSV file Smooks, and split the same into small CSV or XML files. I have tried this against a big XML file which I split and transformed into another form of an XML object-it worked fine. But in this case, I have a CSV file similar to this.

```
HEADER,val01,val02,,,
LINE,lineVal01,lineVal02,lineVal03,lineVal04,lineVal05
LINE,lineVal01,lineVal02,lineVal03,lineVal04,lineVal05
LINE,lineVal01,lineVal02,lineVal03,lineVal04,lineVal05
LINE,lineVal01,lineVal02,lineVal03,lineVal04,lineVal05
```

While doing the java bean binding, I need to read this header separately and generate small CSV/XML files that represent each LINE record containing HEADER info within those.
Eg:

```
<obj>
    <header>
        <Prop01>val01</Prop01>
        <Prop02>val02</Prop02>
    </header>
    <line>
        <prop01>lineVal01</prop01>
        <prop02>ineVal02</prop02>
        <prop03>lineVal03</prop03>
        <prop04>lineVal04</prop04>
        <prop05>lineVal05</prop05>
    <line>
</obj>
```

What should I do in order to identify and use the very first record values within all the output objects?

Will I be able to read it into a java bean like,

```
<jb:bean beanId="header" class="org.me.Header" createOnElement="csv-set/csv-record[0]">
```

Any help is appreciated!!!

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure whether Smooks use xpath expressions in this. However, I'll also try with **csv-set/csv-record[1]** for the header record and **csv-set/csv-record[position()>1]** for the rest of the records. I would leave this Question unedited and un-deleted so that somebody else would find this helpful in future.

Comment: **csv-set/csv-record[1]** just worked fine. But **csv-set/csv-record[position()>1]** throws errors. Apparently, SAX does not support **position()** :(